# Where is createEnvelopeFromDocument() documented?

Tags: docusignapi

I am, more or less contentedly, using the DocuSign REST API through DocuSign's PHP library.  I've imitated model code such as [this](http://social.gseosem.com/docusign-rest-api-can-t-control-document-visibility-on-envelopes-from-documents/):

```
$options = array(
  "enforceSignerVisibility" => true,
);

$response = $service->signature->createEnvelopeFromDocument( 
  $emailSubject,
  $emailBlurb,
  $status,
  $documents,                                                                
  $recipients,
  $eventNotifications,
  $options
);
```

Now it's time to customize my envelope a bit more carefully:  I want to set the address which will receive bounce notices, add a few Bcc recipients, and so on.  Presumably all that will fit in `$options` somehow.  I've located no documentation that I can interpret that way, though; certainly nothing I've found [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/) has moved me forward.

How is `$options` defined?  Where is it documented?  How, specifically, can I customize the e-mail headers that result from use of `createEnvelopeFromDocument()`?

Comment: I like to think [this table][3] from DocuSign has what I seek; I certainly haven't been able to work out the answer, though.  Also, I've somehow managed to lose the thousand-plus reputation I'd accumulated earlier with SO, so it appears I'm limited to a pair of hyperlinks at a time.

Comment: You can indeed specify the reply-to and BCC email addresses (up to 5) for any given envelope. There is no option for custom email x-headers though. Will defer to the answer below regarding the SDK to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the officially supported DocuSign PHP Client (I can tell from the function name you've referenced).  DocuSign now uses auto-generated SDKs from Swagger which I recommend you use- check out the [DocuSign SDKs](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#sdk-docusign) section of the Dev Center. You can also see an example of the PHP SDK in the QuickStart section.

The [API docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/) you've referenced use a [Category->Resource->method] based representation of the DocuSign eSignature REST API. Therefore you want the [Envelopes: create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) method.

Comment: Thank you!  I look forward to working through this corrected approach.